# Cakephp 3: Plugin is not loading component from AppController

Tags: components, cakephp-3.0

I load some components in app/Controller/AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{

  public function initialize()
  {
      parent::initialize();

      $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
      $this->loadComponent('Auth');
  }
}
```

beforeFilter() method is defined inside:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    if ($this->Auth->isAnonymous() && $this->request->query('token')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        }
    }
}
```

When plugin is executed, I get 'Call to a member function isAnonymous() on boolean' error. It means that $this->Auth is false. It is because 'Auth' component is not loaded.

So, I have a plugin named Files where I defined AppController as:

```
use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;

class AppController extends BaseController
{

}
```

It is empty.
This file is in plugin/src/Controller/AppController.
I don't understand the error. Is not it supposed to that if this controller extends of main AppController, components should be loaded?

Comment: so where have you defined isAnonymous ?

Comment: Hi. I defined isAnonymous method in a trait that I call in AuthComponent (app/controller/component/AuthComponent). This component is called in AppController. But isAnonymous method is working well, who is failing is Auth component.